# Switch between min heap and max heap based on a flag

Tags: c++, stl

I have defined a minheap as follows

```
typedef priority_queue<megePartitions_t,vector<megePartitions_t>,compareMergePartition> mergePartitionFilesQ_t;
```

The comparator is defined as follows

```
struct compareMergePartition
{
   bool operator()(const megePartitions_t &lhs,const megePartitions_t &rhs)
   {
      return *(lhs._pair) > *(rhs._pair);
   }
};
```

I am using the defined minheap as follows

```
mergePartitionFilesQ_t mergeQ
```

Now, I want to switch between minheap and maxheap based on a flag, Should I change the comparator's constructor to take in the flag and use it to flip between greater or lesser than comparision or is there a better way. Thank you for your help.

Answer : I felt there is no need for functors so I switched to function pointers, and chose appropriate function based on flag.

```
if(m_builtAcending)
    comparator = compareMergePartitionAsc;
else
    comparator = compareMergePartitionDes;
mergePartitionFilesQ_t mergeQ(comparator);
```

Thank you freitass for your help

Comment: @john Do you mean, two different functors, how to typedef the priority queue ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further? Do you want to take a currently existing heap, switch the flag, and then re-run `make_heap` on it to change from min to max or the reverse?

Comment: @MarkB No I dont want to rebuild existing heap based on the flag, This is what I want while declaring the heap object, "mergePartitionFilesQ_t mergeQ" the mergeQ can be either minHeap or maxHeap based on a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a constructor to your functor that receives a comparison function and instantiate it passing `std::less` or `std::greater`, as follows:

```
template<class Comp>
struct compareMergePartition
{
   Comp comp;
   compareMergePartition(Comp comp) : comp(comp) {}
   bool operator()(const megePartitions_t &lhs,const megePartitions_t &rhs)
   {
      return comp(*(lhs._pair), *(rhs._pair));
   }
};

// Min heap
typedef priority_queue<megePartitions_t,vector<megePartitions_t>,compareMergePartition(std::less<megePartitions_t>())> mergePartitionFilesQ_t;

// Max heap
typedef priority_queue<megePartitions_t,vector<megePartitions_t>,compareMergePartition(std::greater<megePartitions_t>())> mergePartitionFilesQ_t;
```

**Edit:** This answer was given assuming you know what you want at construction time. It is not suitable for on-the-fly changes.

Comment: @freitass You have templated the functor, but not using it so

Comment: @Gopikanna it's not necessary to explicitly specify the type since it can be inferred by the constructor's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a constructor as you mentioned, but since when you change the flag your data order will not be correct; you'll have to reconstruct the whole priority queue. So maybe you can have two queues, one for min-heap and one for max-heap? And copy the data to the other when the flag's value is changed? (Implementation provided by freitass is a good one IMHO)